# How to make Capybara do a DELETE request in a Cucumber feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing, capybara

I am using Cucumber and Capybara. I need to make an HTTP `DELETE` request. Previously the features used webrat, so a simple statement like

```
visit "/comment/" + comment_id, :delete
```

worked, but now I am using Capybara.

The way to do a `GET` request is simply:

```
get 'path'
```

And to do a post request:

```
page.driver.post 'path'
```

But how can I simulate a `DELETE` request?

I found out that the driver Capybara is using is `Capybara::RackTest::Driver`, if that is any help.

I have also tried:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.delete "/comments/" + comment_id
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Is there not a link or a button on your webpage that will trigger the deletion? Cucumber features are supposed to be a full-stack acceptance test. Your feature steps should take you through a happy flow of the application. You should follow links and press buttons and fill in data, etc, and then you could trigger that deletion simply by doing that.

Comment: what you are suggesting would be a preferred way to do so when i write new tests, but currently i am migrating from webrat to capybara. i dont want to modify the 30 or so tests by rewriting them, i want to first make them work using capybara, and then may be rewrite those later as needed.

Comment: really weird, because those methods are included in tha RackTest driver: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb#L78

Answer (score 30):

```
page.driver.submit :delete, "/comments/#{comment_id}", {}
```

Documentation at: http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/1.1.2/Capybara/RackTest/Browser:submit

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this method is unique to the RackTest driver, so this won't work in Selenium or Capybara-webkit.

Comment: This works just fine for capybara-webkit (and I suspect it does for selenium, as well).

Comment: +1 thank god for this. It's certainly not a technique that you need when testing "happy paths", but this is making it miles easier for me to test access control & ensure my before filters are working properly.

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using a driver that doesn't support custom HTTP requests (e.g. Capybara-webkit, see [closed issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/180) and current [driver](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara-webkit/Capybara/Webkit/Driver)), you could just temporary switch to RackTest driver to submit your request.

For example:

```
# Submit an HTTP delete request, using rack_test driver
def http_delete path
  current_driver = Capybara.current_driver
  Capybara.current_driver = :rack_test
  page.driver.submit :delete, path, {}
  Capybara.current_driver = current_driver
end
```

Comment: This solution is much better. Who knows what driver you'll use in future.

Comment: This solution has one (potentially) big problem: It will not retain any session or cookie information from previous requests. So, e.g., if you need to make a `DELETE` request as an authenticated user, this code will probably not work (unless you're already using the `:rack_test` driver). See [my proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36580783/119363) for a method that will retain session info.

Answer (score 2):

```
page.driver.delete("/comments/#{comment_id}")
```

Use `delete` works fine. No need to use the lower level `submit` method for this.

PS: tested with capybara-webkit 1.6.0 and capybara 2.4.4

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution that will *retain session information* (e.g., if you need your `DELETE` request to be issued as an authenticated user), and that will work with both the `:rack_test` driver *and* the `:webkit` driver (assuming you have jQuery available in your app), try something like this:

```
def manual_http_request(method, path)
  if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
    page.driver.submit method, path, {}
  else
    page.execute_script("$.ajax({url: '#{path}', data: {}, type: '#{method}'});")
    # Wait for the request to finish executing...
    Timeout.timeout(10) { loop until page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero? }
  end
end
```

I suspect this will also work with the `:selenium` driver but have not tested it. Maybe someone else can chime in on that.

Comment: This is nice! I did not need the timeout with selenium and chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

This works in selenium. It's assuming you have a logout button/link on any page it is called on

Instead of:

```
visit '/logout'
```

Do:

```
def logout_user
  logout_link = page.first('#my_css_selector')
  logout_link.click if logout_link
end

#... elsewhere in a step
logout_user
```